# Invalid constant name in pylint

Tags: python, pylint

I have a `setup.py` file for my module which, among other things, specifies libraries and sources for c-extensions. Here is an example snippet:

```
LIBRARIES = ['m', 'blas', 'lapacke']
SOURCES = [os.path.join(PATH, 'ext', x) for x in
           ['my_ext1.c', 'my_ext2.c']]
EXT_MODULE = Extension('mymodule.ext.myext', libraries=LIBRARIES,
                       sources=SOURCES)
setup(name='myext', description='C extension', \
      include_dirs=[np.get_include()], ext_modules=[EXT_MODULE])
```

For "LIBRARIES", "SOURCES", and "EXT_MODULES", I believe I am accurately following the [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) naming convention for consants, since these are globally defined in `setup`. However, pylint keeps giving me "Invalid constant name 'NAME' (invalid-name)" for NAME=LIBRARIES, etc. I am getting the same message for more benign declarations in another module as well (which only holds constants). The entire module has this form

```
""" Model Consants """

BETA = .99
N_SIMS = 1000
N_PERIODS = 200
```

and I'm getting the message for all of these declarations. Like I said, I believe I'm following PEP8 on all of this and I can't see any obvious violations of the pylint [regex rules](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#basic-checker). Am I missing something?

Comment: When I run pylint, the first example doesn't produce those errors, and the 2nd example doesn't produce any errors at all. Please include  the pylint command line and pylint output you are seeing.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for asking that. I had added the pylint call to my testing routine and forgot that I had changed the `const-rgx` based on another version of the project. It's always the small, silly things, isn't it?

Comment: The lesson to learn from this is: always provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) / [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org).